# Changing the \title in amsart

Tags: titles, amsart

I am new to `amsart`.  I want to give myself a default running header.  So I try to redefine `\title` in the obvious way as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\let\AmStitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[2][My default running title]{\AmStitle[#1]{#2}}

\title{Article title here}
\author{Author name here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This apparently ends up looping indefinitely.  What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro `\title` in `amsart` is defined in a very indirect way:

```
\renewcommand*{\title}[2][]{\gdef\shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}}
\edef\title{\@nx\@dblarg
  \@xp\@nx\csname\string\title\endcsname}
```

which is very clever, but simply disallows you to do that redefinition. In this case even `\LetLtxMacro` is not good, because of this nonstandard definition.

You can do it with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\title}{om}{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}
     {\gdef\shorttitle{My default running title}}
     {\gdef\shorttitle{#1}}%
   \gdef\@title{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\title{Article title here}
\author{Author name here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

Actually, it's a bit mysterious why the definition of `\title` is that one. The standard way to define a macro of that kind would be

```
\def\title{\@dblarg\title@}
\def\title@[#1]#2{%
  \gdef\shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}%
}
```

because `\@dblarg` takes care that a call such as

```
\title{Title}
```

will substitute `Title` both for `#1` and `#2`, while a call such as

```
\title[Short]{Long title}
```

will do the expected thing. Instead of `\title@` anything else could be used.

The definition in `amsart` exploits the fact that

```
\renewcommand*{\title}[2][]{\gdef\shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}}
```

defines `\title` to expand to

```
\@protected@testopt\title\\title{}
```

and `\\title` (a command with a backslash in its name) as if

```
\def\\title[#1]#2{\gdef\shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}}
```

The next instruction, with `\@nx` and `\@xp` replaced by the more comprehensible `\noexpand` and `\expandafter`, is

```
\edef\title{%
  \noexpand\@dblarg\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string\title\endcsname
}
```

that is essentially the same as saying

```
\def\title{\@dblarg\\title}
```

(with the difference that `\\title` needs wome weird trick for being input). So there is no gain whatsoever, because the definition is eventually *exactly** the easier one I gave before, except perhaps that the internal macro (`\\title`, here) is more difficult to get at for a casual user.

The `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package can't work, because `\\title` exists, but `\title` is not defined as expected, that is, starting with `\@protected@testopt`, so it gets confused.

The `xparse` way is surely clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer!  I suppose there are other people like me who are too lazy to chase back definitions.  So, could you explain in a couple of sentences how the indirect definition works (or perhaps say it is not possible to do so), please?

Comment: @LawrenceWong Your wish is my command

Comment: Very clear and detailed.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

you can change the title for just one article by adding, after `\maketitle`,

```
\markright{My default running title}
```

or, if you want it on both sides,

```
\markboth{My default running title}
```

this does have the disadvantage that it doesn't automatically uppercase the string,
so you either need to type it in fully "cased", or apply `\MakeTextUppercase{...}`.